# I see "Server Application Unavailable" with IIS 5.1

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-5

[alt text http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/2488/79392512.jpg](http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/2488/79392512.jpg)

I shared maximum permissions there and there nothing in the log. I can't understand where this error comes from.

Comment: Are you sure you're checking the correct log?  You want to look at the Windows application log (`Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer`), and not the IIS logfiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reason that this may happens is because of crash of iis Admin 5.1. This happens a lot especial if you programming and make difficult thinks, or just a bad loop on your program can make this happens.

How to solve this.

1. on your website properties on Connections UNCHECK http Keep-Alives Enable.
2. restart the IIS Admin (and not only the "world wide web publishing") when you have problems.
3. Use the Process Explorer and check the iis admin and the www service that is running and not stack.

If any of this services has stack, then kill it from Process Explorer and then make IIS Admin restart.

When you restart IIS Admin, then the www is restarting also, but if fails to restart for sure you need to kill it with Process Explorer.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I seen usually with the mix of .Net versions deployed in IIS (ASP.Net).
Just ensure one is there.
if you have later versions of IIS then you can segregate different versions with the different worker process.
Hope it gives you some clue..